# Check if a template exists within a Django template

Tags: django, templates, try-catch, exists

Is there an out-of-the-box way of checking if a template exists before including it in a Django template?  Alternatives are welcome too but some of them would not work due to the particular circumstances.

For example, here's an answer to a slightly different question.  This is not what I'm looking for:
[How to check if a template exists in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690213/how-to-check-if-a-template-exists-in-django)

Answer (score 19):

Assuming `include` doesn't blow up if you pass it a bad template reference, that's probably the best way to go. Your other alternative would be to create a template tag that essentially does the checks in the link you mentioned.

Very basic implementation:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def template_exists(template_name):
    try:
        django.template.loader.get_template(template_name)
        return "Template exists"
    except template.TemplateDoesNotExist:
        return "Template doesn't exist"
```

In your template:

```
{% template_exists 'someapp/sometemplate.html' %}
```

That tag isn't really all that useful, so you'd probably want to create one that actually adds a variable to the context, which you could then check in an if statement or what not.

Answer (score 13):

I encountered this trying to display a template only if it exists, and wound up with the following template tag solution:

### Include a template only if it exists

Put the following into `yourapp/templatetags/include_maybe.py`

```
from django import template
from django.template.loader_tags import do_include
from django.template.defaulttags import CommentNode
register = template.Library()

@register.tag('include_maybe')
def do_include_maybe(parser, token):
    "Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18951166/15690"
    bits = token.split_contents()
    if len(bits) < 2:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError(
            "%r tag takes at least one argument: "
            "the name of the template to be included." % bits[0])

    try:
        silent_node = do_include(parser, token)
    except template.TemplateDoesNotExist:
        # Django < 1.7
        return CommentNode()

    _orig_render = silent_node.render
    def wrapped_render(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return _orig_render(*args, **kwargs)
        except template.TemplateDoesNotExist:
            return CommentNode()
    silent_node.render = wrapped_render
    return silent_node
```

Access it from your templates by adding `{% load include_maybe %}` at the top of your template, and using `{% include_maybe "my_template_name.html" %}` in code.

This approach has the nice side effect of piggy-backing the existing template include tag, so you can pass in context variables in the same way that you can with a plain `{% include %}`.

### Switch based on whether a template exists

However, I wanted some additional formatting on the embedding site if the template existed. Rather than writing an `{% if_template_exists %}` tag, I wrote a filter that lets you work with the existing `{% if %}` tag.

To this end, put the following into `yourapp/templatetags/include_maybe.py` (or something else)

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter


register = template.Library()

@register.filter
@stringfilter
def template_exists(value):
    try:
        template.loader.get_template(value)
        return True
    except template.TemplateDoesNotExist:
        return False
```

And then, from your template, you can do something like:

```
{% load include_maybe %}

{% if "my_template_name"|template_exists %}
     <div>
         <h1>Notice!</h1>
         <div class="included">
             {% include_maybe "my_template_name" %}
         </div>
     </div>
{% endif %}
```

The advantage of using a custom filter over using a custom tag is that you can do things like:

```
{% if "my_template_name"|template_exists and user.is_authenticated %}...{% endif %}
```

instead of using multiple `{% if %}` tags.

Note that you still have to use `include_maybe`.

Comment: `do_include_maybe` stopped working with Django 1.7 ([traceback](http://dpaste.com/1ZXQFN4)). It seems like the exception gets thrown later now, and not from `do_include` anymore. I've fixed it above, by trying to fetch the template always.

Comment: +1 Hey I just called you, and this is crazy, but here my template, so `include_maybe`.

Comment: Do you have to do the `template.loader.get_template` bit?  If you just do `return do_include(parser, token)` shouldn't that by-itself throw a TemplateDoesNotExist exception?

Comment: @Lochlan Possibly! Although it would actually go ahead and execute that template too, which may be slow.

Comment: @Lochlan the extra call was meant for Django 1.7, but it appears to have stopped working there, too - also when using `bits[1]`, which appears to be more correct.  I'll update the code for what appears to work with Django 1.7 and hopefully older versions.

Answer (score 4):

I needed to conditionally include templates if they exist but I wanted to use a variable to store the template name like you can do with the regular `{% include %}` tag.

Here's my solution which I've used with Django 1.7:

```
from django import template
from django.template.loader_tags import do_include

register = template.Library()


class TryIncludeNode(template.Node):
    """
    A Node that instantiates an IncludeNode but wraps its render() in a
    try/except in case the template doesn't exist.
    """
    def __init__(self, parser, token):
        self.include_node = do_include(parser, token)

    def render(self, context):
        try:
            return self.include_node.render(context)
        except template.TemplateDoesNotExist:
            return ''


@register.tag('try_include')
def try_include(parser, token):
    """
    Include the specified template but only if it exists.
    """
    return TryIncludeNode(parser, token)
```

In a Django template it might be used like this:

```
{% try_include "template-that-might-not-exist.html" %}
```

Or, if the template name is in a variable called `template_name`:

```
{% try_include template_name %}
```

Comment: Works like a charm in 2+ too!

Comment: An example of this in use (what are parser and token for example) would be useful.

Comment: @BerndWechner `parser` and `token` are passed to template tags, and the `@register.tag('try_include')` decorator registers this as a template tag... I will add an example of its use in a template :)

Answer (score 1):

[`include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include) accepts variables:

```
{% include template_name %}
```

so you could do the check in your view.

Comment: Wouldn't that raise a TemplateDoesNotExist exception if the template doesn't exist?

Comment: Okay, i meant to pass the template-variable only if the template exists (and to catch a potential exception in the view). Thatway one could easily wrap the the `include` in a check for the variable. But of course that's not ideal and a dedicated tag, as you suggested, is probably better.