# Django: Include template with constructed name if available

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a one template say:

`default_form.html`

which receives in its context a variable, say `variant`.

I can of course render the contents of the variable with `{{ variant }}`

And here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28076380/4002633

I see a wonderful way to load a template if it exists. It works nicely if I have a template called `variant` as follows:

`{% try_include variant %}`

But I am hoping to go one step further. I would like to use a constructed template name, in the example above and include if it exists a template named `default_form_variant.html`.

I imagine something like this:

`{% try_include "default_form_{{variant}}.html" %}`

but even more general rather than encoding the current template's name, getting that, if possible, from the context itself or in a custom tag from the parser.

I am struggling to see how and where in the custom tag definition I'd have access to three things at once:

1. The name of the current template: `default_form.html` in this case.
2. The argument to the tag: `variant` in this case
3. The ability to construct a template name from the first two (easy enough with os.path) and inject it into the do_include handler.

Comment: Change `"default_form_{{variant}}.html"` to `"default_form%s.html"` pass an extra argument and format. Non-existent variables are treated as empty string I think so you can check easily.

Comment: A good start, but I'd like to avoid hardcoding `default_form.html` and get that name form the context somehow? This idea is ncie and I could do `{% try_include "default_form.html" {{variant}}%}` (two arguments) and cobble them together, but neither do I want to use the string literal nor do I know where to put the cobbled together string. I could try replacing `token[]1` in the custom tag defintion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as no-one was rushing to answer this I experimented with the wonderful solution to another problem posted here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28076380/4002633

at some length and have implemented the following with success:

```py
class IncludeVariant(template.Node):
    '''
    A Template Node that tries to include a template file named as a variant 
    of the file it's included in. That is if it's in a template named:
    
        form_data.html
    
    as:
    
        {% include_variant context_var %}
    
    it will try and include:
    
        form_data_context_var.html
    
    where context_var is a context variable.
    
    For help on custom template tags: 
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-the-compilation-function
    '''
    def __init__(self, parser, token):
        self.parser  = parser
        self.token   = token

    def render(self, context):
        try:
            words = self.token.split_contents()
            variant = context.get(self.token.contents.split()[1], self.token.contents.split()[1])
            path    = context.template_name
            parts   = os.path.splitext(path)
            words[1] = f"'{parts[0]}_{variant}{parts[1]}'"
            self.token.contents = " ".join(words)
            include = do_include(self.parser, self.token)
            return include.render(context)
        except template.TemplateDoesNotExist:
            return ''


@register.tag('include_variant')
def include_variant(parser, token):
    '''
    Include the specified variant on this template but only if it exists.
    
    :param parser:
    :param token:
    '''
    return IncludeVariant(parser, token)
```

It is a mildly risky approach in that it rests on premises that stood up to empirical testing but I can't find clear documentation for. Namely that we can rebuild the passed-in token as I have done (a re-join of a token.split_contents()) and that this is robust. It certainly seems to be and inspecting do_include() I am satisfied it's functional.

This permits me to include variants of the current template based on the contents of a context variable.