# Catching TemplateDoesNotExist in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use the templatetag described in SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6217194/493211 in a project using Django 1.4.3 (with Python 2.7.2).

I adapted it like this:

```
from django import template


register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def template_exists(template_name):
    try:
        template.loader.get_template(template_name)
        return True
    except template.TemplateDoesNotExist:
        return False
```

So that I could use it like this in another template:

```
{% if 'profile/header.html'|template_exists %}        
  {% include 'profile/header.html' %}
{% else %}
  {% include 'common/header.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

This way, I could have avoided using solutions such as changing the order of my apps in INSTALLED_APPS.

However, it does not work. If the template **does not** exist, then the exception is raised within the stack/console but it is not propagated up to `get_template(..)` (from inside this [statement](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.3/django/template/loader.py#L140)), and thus not to my *foolish* API. Hence, this blows up in my face during the rendering. I uploaded the stacktrace to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/3Yfzkmyj)

Is this a wanted behavior from Django?

I ended up stop doing foolish things as is. But my question would remain.

Comment: What happens when you try to catch `template.loader.TemplateDoesNotExist`?

Comment: Thanks for jumping in. I get the same stack

Comment: I posted an answer which is actually a workaround and I wouldn't mind a "real" explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a custom tag? This doesn't provide the full functionality of `include` but seems to meet the needs in the question.:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def include_fallback(context, *template_choices):
    t = django.template.loader.select_template(template_choices)
    return t.render(context)
```

Then in your template:

```
{% include_fallback "profile/header.html" "common/header.html" %}
```

Comment: @Marc-OlivierTiteux I got around to doing some quick testing, at least of the fallback and inclusion behavior and that context variables in the parent template were available to the included template and it worked for me.  Let me know how this works for you.

Comment: Also note that this quick pass doesn't provide the ``with`` or ``only`` arguments of the default ``include`` template tag. You could modify the ``include_fallback`` to do this without too much trouble by using the ``include`` implementation as a reference, but the additional functionality didn't seem to be required in the original question.

Comment: Thanks it works. Actually, my use case was: if the template does not exist, just do nothing. In this case, if I put {% include_fallback "profile/header.html" "" %}, it does not work. But it works great in the context of the question so I validate your answer. I will keep this answer in mind though!

Answer (score 1):

I found some kind of an answer to my question so I am posting it here for future refence.

If I use my template_exists filter like this

```
{% if 'profile/header.html'|template_exists %}        
  {% include 'profile/header.html' %}
{% else %}
  {% include 'common/header.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

and if `profile/header.html` does not exist, then the TemplateDoesNotExist gets strangely propagated at page load and I get a server error. However, if instead, I use this in my template:

```
{% with 'profile/header.html' as var_templ %}
  {% if var_templ|template_exists %}
    {% include var_templ %}
  {% else %}
    {% include 'common/header.html' %}
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Then, it works like a charm!

Obviously, I could have used

```
django.template.loader.select_template(['profile/header.html','common/header.html'])
```

in the view (from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10882049/493211)). But I am using a CBV which I wanted to keep rather generic and this was called from the main template. And also I thought it would be nice to have my site working if this apps goes down for whatever reason. If this seems silly to you, please leave a comment (or yet a better answer).